# Rails fixtures' ids versus labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got this legacy rails 2.3 project with fixtures that I'm trying to work with, and I'm having troubles with fixtures trying to insert a label to another fixture as-is into the table (and then failing with "column not found" for the entity name, "employee" -- there is the appropriate belongs_to :employee in the model).

So what exactly are the rules as to when the fixtures use a label and when you have to give an explicit id? It does not seem to work so that when you give an id, you have to then also use it. Quite often a label just does not get used for some reason even when there is no explicit id, and I'm not getting it why...

Answer (score 1):

Rails 2.3 **should** (assuming no meddling) have Foxy Fixtures, in which case the rules are the same as they are today:

- If you're specifying the column name, e.g. `ship_id:`, you must define and use an ID.
- If you're specifying the relation name, e.g. `ship:`, you must use the label. The fixture need not have an ID defined.

> ```
> # contacts.yml
> jean_luc:
>   rank: captain
>   ship: enterprise    # no _id, use label
>   nationality: French
> khan:
>   rank: admiral
>   ship_id: 145        # id, use id
>   nationality: Test Tube
>
> # ships.yml
> enterprise:
>   # could define id here, but it's not required 
>   name: Enterprise
>   registry: NCC-1701-D
> botany_bay:
>   id: 145  # Since we're using ship_id, this is required.
>   name: Botany Bay
>   registry: Unknown
> ```